# How to load the block with Header,Footer,Left navigation, Right navigation in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to load the block with Header, Footer, Left navigation, Right navigation in Magento 2?

step by step please tell me

Comment: load block means ? static cms block could you define your question in detail

Comment: yes static cms block on home page to show header footer left nevigation ,right navigation all

Answer (score 0):

Create cms block and add that block id in your layout file , i.e You have created new cms block and its id is `custom-block` and you want to add that block in footer then in your theme's default.xml file add block code :

```
<!-- Footer Section -->
<referenceContainer name="footer" htmlClass="footer content">
    <container name="footer-col3" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-12">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-custom" before="-">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom-block</argument>
          </arguments>
       </block>
   </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

so this piece of code :

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-custom" before="-">
    <arguments>
       <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom-block</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

you would need to add where ever you need to call that block :

NOTE : change block name "**footer-custom**" for other sections , otherwise it will load that block only once.